# Generate a new vector out of blocks of a given vector

Tags: c++, random, vector

I have a `std::vector` with roughly 1 million values stored in it. Now I want to divide the vector into N blocks with a given size and create a new `std::vector` by pulling randomly N blocks out of the original vector. Here is what I have so far, this is just for getting an Idea.

```
int main {  
    int breakPoint = 2;
    std::vector<int> test = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    std::vector<int> newTest;
    int length = test.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int foo = random(breakPoint,length);
        //std::cout << foo << std::endl;
        std::vector<int> subvector(test.begin() + foo, test.begin() + foo + breakPoint);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < subvector.size(); i++){
            newTest.push_back(subvector[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int random(int N, int interval){
    int rnd;

    int foo = 1;
    while (foo !=0) {
        rnd = int(randomNumber(0, (interval+1-N)));
        foo = (rnd%N);
    }
    return rnd;
}
```

`randomNumber(a,b)` gives an random number in the interval [a,b). This code runs and for not too large vectors I would use it this way. But since I have a large orignial vector and I will have to repeat this new vector operations many times, to gain statistics, I would rather not use this. So my question is, how to make such an operation very fast? The first problem is obviously how I select a breakpoint in `random()`.
Thank you for helping me, cheers!

Comment: If the large vector will stick around, perhaps your new vectors can contain only pointers/iterators into the original vector's data, and not the whole data, to save space?

Comment: Why first initialize a `subvector` and then copy it to `newTest`? You can simply use `std::copy` with `std::back_inserter`  to append your data. Also, why copy at all? Just hand out `iterator` pairs to the blocks.

Comment: Why is selecting a breakpoint a problem? May vector blocks overlap each other? Have you considered exporting your vector from c++ to something like R for statistical analysis?

Comment: Selecting a block is not the problem, it is just a performance issue selecting one randomly.  No the blocks do not overlap. I have considered it, but I have only little experience in R. Is it powerful/fast in evaluating large amount of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have suggested for a very large `test` this code is going to bog down a lot in the copy process, the solution would be to not copy. (Say test contains a million elements, that means you're going to do 4 million random accesses *just to copy*.)

Keeping an iterator into is a simple way to index into `test` as long as `test` remains unchanged.

```
const auto breakPoint = 2;
const std::vector<int> test = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
vector<vector<int>::const_iterator> newTest(test.size());

for(auto& i : newTest){
    i = test.begin() + random(breakPoint, test.size());
}
```

Keeping iterators in a vector allows us to sort them, *before ever accessing memory*. So we can take advantage of the cache's spatial locality.

```
sort(newTest.begin(), newTest.end());
```

Now to work with `newTest` you can just do something like this:

```
for(auto& i : newTest){
    for_each(i, i + breakPoint, [](int foo){cout << foo << ' ';});
    cout << endl;
}
```

**EDIT:**

`random` does not seem like a huge time suck in the grand scheme of things because it doesn't do memory access, but you could improve it by searching for an appropriate `breakPoint` multiplier, rather than trying to randomly find an `breakPoint` increment:

```
// This change assumes that you've already done srand(time(nullptr));
int random(int N, int interval){
    return (rand() % (interval / N)) * N;
}
```

You can see how something this simple could just be inlined, and that would provide the further benefit of allowing `interval / N` to only be calculated once. So our initialization section can now become:

```
const auto breakPoint = 2;
const std::vector<int> test = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
const auto partitions = test.size() / breakPoint;
vector<vector<int>::const_iterator> newTest(test.size());

srand(time(nullptr));

for(auto& i : newTest){
    i = test.begin() + breakPoint * (rand() % partitions);
}
```

Comment: I do not exactly understand this part her `[](int foo){cout << foo;}` . I see what it does, but I have never seen this notation. And in `for(auto& i : newTest)` the i is not just an Alias, it is then really the adress over which we iterate?

Comment: @nerdizzle So [`for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) is going to call that function on every element in its range. What your comment is about specifically is a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). If you find yourself needing more help understanding lambdas we should probably open a new question as it's kind of outside scope. Simply put `[](int foo){cout << foo;}` will capture nothing from local scope, it will take an `int` as an argument, and it will print that `int`

Comment: I will read about the lambda functions by myself. One other thing thats bothering me is the evaluation of the  `random()` function, this is pretty costly and the cost increases with the length of the breakPoints. How can that be improved?

Comment: @nerdizzle OK I've edited. If you have questions let me know.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [std::vector::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) to append the random block to the output vector:

```
std::vector<int> input = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
std::vector<int> output;

for (size_t i = 0; i != num_blocks; i++) {
    int block_position = getRandomBlock(num_blocks, block_length);
    auto block_begin = input.cbegin() + block_position;
    auto block_end = block_begin + block_length;
    output.insert(output.end(), block_begin, block_end);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I looked at and while testing it something came into my mind. namely, what if we would have  `std::vector< std::vector<int> > input`, where the data is in the columns. The code above can be easily adabted for this problem. But then one needs an iterator over the columns, how would that look like? I tried `input[k].cbegin()` but this is an iterator for the k-th row..

Comment: There is no easy way of iterating over the "columns" of a 2D vector, the data is ordered along the "rows" so you would be jumping about in memory. You could perhaps make your own iterator to do it but that is beyond the scope of this answer. For something simple I would just write your own loop.

Comment: so if I had the data stored in the "rows" I could use  `input[k].cbegin()` to iterate over them?

Comment: Yes, you could easily change the `insert` above to `output.insert(output.end(), row.cbegin(), row.cend())`